# How to list items in a list and remove duplicates in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry if i'm asking the wrong way. I'm still a beginner.

I have a list that renders some products. These products are divided into categories, some products may have more than one category.

The image below shows the categories of each product:

[image]

What I would like to do is create a list with all categories (without duplication) and show it to the user.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import data from "./data";
import Categories from "./components/Categories";

export default function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(data);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>List Categories</h1>
      {products.map((item) => (
        <Categories key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I put my code into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/remove-duplicate-list-array-nd59y?file=/src/App.js)

Can you tell me how I can do that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const allCategories = data.reduce((p,c)=> [...p, ...c.categories],[])
   .filter((elem, index, self) => index === self.indexOf(elem))
```

Comment: Hey Damian, that's work perfectly for me, thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Set` this will remove all of the duplicates in your list

```
    const allCat = [...new Set(data.flat())]
```

you could read more in docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: add some description for your answer